# module not found error when trying to import components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, node-modules, vercel

I am working on my portfolio website and am learning NEXT.JS because I want to deploy with vercel. Not sure why but I am getting a module not found error and it is related to my imports but my pathing is correct and my file names match so I am not sure why this is happening. I am exporting my functions in each file as well. Any help would be appreciated.

These are my file names:

```
import ProjectCard from '../src/app/components/ProjectCard';
import AboutMe from '../src/app/components/AboutMe';
import ContactForm from '../src/app/components/ContactForm';
import Header from '../src/app/components/Header';
```

ProjectCard
Header
ContactForm
AboutMe

I do not get an error when I use standard camel casing for my file names instead of pascal naming convention but this would not properly call the functions from my path.

Comment: Hey, What is the location of this file? Ex: `src/modules/App.tsx`